# Convert a newline separated string list into a comma separated list all on one line enclosed by square brackets using RegEx

Tags: regex

If given:

```
tst_btn = Button(tli,21)
set_blinking = Button(tli,22)
set_enable = Button(tli,23)
set_state = Button(tli,24)
set_text = Button(tli,25)
set_visible = Button(tli,26)
tst_label = Label(tli,31)
set_enable2 = Button(tli,32)
set_text2 = Button(tli,33)
set_visible2 = Button(tli,34)
inc = Button(tli,41)
dec = Button(tli,41)
set_level = Button(tli,41)
set_enable3 = Button(tli,41)
set_visible3 = Button(tli,41)
v_level = Level(tli,301)
h_level = Level(tli,302)
slide = Slider(tli,1)
slide2 = Slider(tli,2)
host1 = Button(tli,131)
id1 = Button(tli,132)
event1 = Button(tli,133)
state1 = Button(tli,134)
host2 = Button(tli,135)
id2 = Button(tli,136)
host3 = Button(tli,137)
id3 = Button(tli,138)
level = Button(tli,139)
mute = Button(tli,140)
uidiag_back = Button(tli,202)
uidiag_next = Button(tli,203)
```

How do I transform above into the following: (brackets included):

```
[uidiag_back, uidiag_next, uitst_btn, set_blinking, set_enable, set_state, set_text, set_enable2, set_text2, set_visible2, inc, dec, set_level, set_enable3, set_visible3, v_level, h_level, slide, slide2, host1, id1, event1, state1,  host2, id2, host3, id3, level, mute, set_visible, tst_label]
```

using RegEx? I can get rid of the RHS for Button, Label, Level, and Slider objects using:

```
 = Button\(tli,[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)| = Button\(tli,[0-9][0-9]\)| = Button\(tli,[0-9]\)| = Label\(tli,[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)| = Label\(tli,[0-9][0-9]\)| = Label\(tli,[0-9]\)| = Button\(tli,[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)| = Button\(tli,[0-9][0-9]\)| = Button\(tli,[0-9]\)|  = Slider\(tli,[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)| = Slider\(tli,[0-9][0-9]\)| = Slider\(tli,[0-9]\)| = Level\(tli,[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)| = Level\(tli,[0-9][0-9]\)| = Level\(tli,[0-9]\)
```

How do I put what is left all on one line, comma separated, enclosed by square brackets like the following:

```
[tst_btn, set_blinking, set_enable, set_state, set_text,(....etc)]
```

When I attempt the following to put everything on one line:

```
(?1[:(?2]:$3, ))
```

only commas are added, but each remain on separate lines.

I'm trying to do this in Notepad++.

Comment: It can be done by using programming language (such as js, c#, php....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++:

- `Find what:    [\n\r]+`
- `Replace with: ,`
- Check the "Wrap around" checkbox
- In Search mode, check "Regular expression", and check ", matches newline"
- Use "Replace All" button

Explanation:

- `[\n\r]+` finds 1+ occurrences of newlines and linefeeds
- `,`  replaces what you have found with comma & space

Comment: never thought to add the []+ around the \n\r, thanks @Peter Thoeny

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the conditional replacement pattern:

**Find What**: `(?s)(^(?<!.))|($(?!.))|([^\r\n]+)\R`
**Replace With**: `(?1[:(?2]:$3, ))`

**Details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL mode, enables *`.` matches newline* option
- `(^(?<!.))` - Capturing group 1: start of a file
- `|` - or
- `($(?!.))` - Capturing group 2: end of a file
- `|` - or
- `([^\r\n]+)\R` - one or more chars other than CR and LF symbols, as many as possible (captured into Group 3), and then a line break sequence

The matches are replaced with:

- `(?1` - If Group 1 matches

  - `[` - replace with `[` (insert at the start)
  - `:` - else
  - `(?2` - If Group 2 matched

    - `]` - replace with `]` (insert `]` at the end)
    - `:` - else
    - `$3,`  - Group 3 and comma + space
  - `)`  - end
- `)` - end

See the Notepad++ settings and demo:

[image]

Comment: Stribizew, your expression find the names but excludes the first letter, your replace expression does nothing. Either way I'm grateful for your reply and explanation.

Comment: @Niko_Jako See my settings, and the result, it works well, as expected. A single search and replace, no need to run S&R several times.